# Creating different directories dynamically for different IP addresses

Tags: java, jsp

I have below code which creates directory dynamically for storing image after it is captured from flash.

I want to create new directory with new name like "terminal_2" (here it creates with name terminal_1), if image captured from different IP Address.

For eg: Currently if my IP Address is 192.113.25.13 then it creates "terminal_1" directory and if my IP address changes to 192.113.37.25 then it should create "terminal_2" directory and store image in "terminal_2" directory.

I know how to catch IP address using java.

```
String fileStoreURL="";
String rootpath="/applicationservices/fileshare/vm/uploads";
fileStoreURL = config.getServletContext().getRealPath("") + rootpath + "/terminal_1";

try {
    File f = new File(fileStoreURL);
    if (!f.exists())
    {
        f.mkdirs();
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{

}

try {
    long time = new Date().getTime();
    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(fileStoreURL + "/"+time+".jpg");
    int res;
    while ((res = request.getInputStream().read()) != -1) {
        fileOutputStream.write(res);
    }

    fileOutputStream.close();
/*
 * To make sure each url is differeent and not cached added time to tit
 */
response.getWriter().append(
"http://localhost/......./fileshare/vm/uploads/terminal_1/" + time+ ".jpg");

} catch (Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
} 
finally 
{   

}
```

Comment: How do you propose to know whether the IP address has change from *the value it was when `terminal_1` was created*?  That's the tricky part of doing this.

Comment: Are you keeping a map or store of the ip-addresses and the directories like:  192.113.25.13 is for terminal_1 directory,  192.113.25.125 for terminal_2,  192.113.25.133 for terminal_3 and so on?

Comment: Andrzej Doyle: Sorry for incomplete questioon .I mean to say, this is a web application and if I access this  application  from different machine then obiviously IP address of that machine is different then that tereminal_2 , terminal_3 etc directory should get generate.

Comment: Prakash K: I want to store image and if I captured it from that 192.113.25.125 machine it should create terminal_1 directory and stored in that or if I captured image from 192.113.25.133 machine then it should get stored in terminal_2 directory and so on

Comment: Is your application stateful? Let's assume 192.113.25.13 is for terminal_1. If you reload the web application or restart the web server do you still expect 192.113.25.13 to be mapped to terminal_1?

Comment: Oded Peer: Yes my application is stateful. IP Address is Fixed wheather restart machine or web server or we application

Comment: @yatinbc you can use `@username` to mark your comments for a specific user. Anyways back to question: one thing is not clear, will you be storing the mapping between IP and the folder names?

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood correctly then (please correct if I am wrong):

1. You need to store images you get from a particular IP address.
2. For every IP you need to create a separate folder like (terminal_1, terminal_2 etc) on the server.
3. Then in that folder you need to store the image which you have got from the particular IP.

You already have done the following things:

1. Get IP address of the machine which is accessing your application.
2. Create a folder on the server
3. Create image inside that folder

Things which are pending:

1. Creating different folders for different IPs.
2. Logic to check if the folder for this IP is already created or not.
3. `if (folder not created) { then create } else { don't create, just save the image}`.

So here is my approach for pending things:

1. You would need to maintain some relationship between the IP address and the folder names, and store it in database or a file (like properties file) on file system on server. Suppose you get an image from 192.168.1.23 and you store it in terminal_1, then you get an image from 192.167.0.34 and you store it in terminal_2, now again you get another image from 192.168.1.23 so would you create a new folder or store the image in terminal_1. So to find out if folder for this IP address (192.167.0.34) is already created you need to maintain some sort of relation between IP address and the folder.
2. Then when you get an image from an IP Address say 192.168.1.23, search for the IP address in your database:

   ```
   if(no mapping found for this IP Address) {
       // 1) create the folder and give some name for eg: terminal_2
       // 2) store this mapping of IP Address and the folder name
       // 3) Save the image inside this folder
   } else if (mapping found) {
       // 1) fetch the folder name
       // 2) Save the image in this folder
   }
   ```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Prakash K: I am not getting your answer.please help

Comment: @yatinbc I have edited my answer, see if this helps. Or else tell me what you have not understood in my answer. Thanks